# Flex-wrap does not affect nested element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Checkout example first: http://jsfiddle.net/8ofrs0y7/14/

```html
     <div class="flex-group">
          <ul class="flex-container red">
            <li class="flex-item">1</li>
            <li class="flex-item">2</li>
            <li class="flex-item">3</li>
          </ul>
        
          <ul class="flex-container gold">
            <li class="flex-item">1</li>
            <li class="flex-item">2</li>
            <li class="flex-item">3</li>
            <li class="flex-item">4</li>
            <li class="flex-item">5</li>
          </ul>
        
          <ul class="flex-container blue">
            <li class="flex-item">1</li>
            <li class="flex-item">2</li>
            <li class="flex-item">3</li>
            <li class="flex-item">4</li>
            <li class="flex-item">5</li>
            <li class="flex-item">6</li>
            <li class="flex-item">7</li>
            <li class="flex-item">8</li>
          </ul>
        <div>
    <style>
        .flex-group {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          width: 500px;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          list-style: none;
        }
        
        .red li {
          background: red;
        }
        
        .gold li {
          background: gold;
        }
        
        .blue li {
          background: deepskyblue;
        }
        
        .flex-item {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          margin-left: 10px
        }
    </style>
```

Every flex-element starts from new line despite of their child elements still able to fit .flex-group container.

Is it possible to place two squares of same color on different lines?

Comment: Please add your CSS to the question as well. See [mcve]

Comment: You're telling it to wrap. Remove your ```flex-wrap``` if you don't want it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the width of the div with the class name flex group to 500px.
Not sure why you have done that.

So just delete `width:500px`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i meant a little bit different. li elements should behave like they are child of .flex-group element, and make a rectangle with optionally filled last line